# How to disable iChat's popup "You are not connected to the internet"?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, ichat

I am tired of seeing the "You are not connected to the internet" message from iChat every time after I open my macbook. I use iChat for screen sharing. Is it possible to disable the annoying popup or should I just use another app for messaging and screen sharing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use another app for screensharing and messaging.  If you choose to do this, I reccomend [Adium](http://www.adium.im) for messaging and [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx) for screensharing.  I searched the contents of the whole iChat application, and I couldn't find anything, which leads me to believe that the pop up (I've had it too) is not actually part of the iChat application, but used by iChat.

Answer (score -1):

Open ichat, close windows, logout. That fixed it for me.

Comment: That's a rather extreme solution for this, don't you think?